# Is it necessary to mention all functions of the wrapped .c file in the interface file using SWIG?

Tags: python, c, interface, wrapper, swig

I try to wrap several .c files to make the accessible via Python. If I want to access all functions of all files do I have to mention all the functions in the interface file?

Comment: What happens if you don't mention all functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But there is a shortcut: SWIG can parse header (`.h`) files. So most of the time, you can get away with this interface file:

```
 %module example
 %{
 /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
 #include "header.h"
 %}

 /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
 %include "header.h"
```

For more information, search for "SWIG for the truly lazy" at http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

Comment: Actually I do not have header files, I have .c files. Can I include them as well as you wrote above?

Comment: 2. Question: if I include the header files like this, all functions inclusive their variables are accessible via python?

Comment: You can try with `.c` files but parsing them is much harder and I don't know how sophisticated the SWIG parser is. 2. Question: Variables are only visible inside of functions, so no. If you mean "function parameters", then yes, SWIG will generate glue code which includes function parameters.