# Python ctypes pointer to struct as identifier without member access

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I have two different C functions and I would like to use them with ctypes in Python.

One function is establishing a connection and returns a pointer to an truct. The pointer shall be used as an argument in the second function to reuse the established connection.

**C Code:**

```
customStruct * connect()
{
    customStruct *obj = connection_helper();
    return obj;
}

void foo(customStruct * obj)
{
    foo_helper(obj);
}
```

**Python code:**

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL("./test.dll")

obj = lib.connect()
lib.foo(obj)
```

Unfortunately, I retrieve access violation errors when I call `lib.foo()`. I could recreate the `customStruct` struct in Python using a class with the `_fields_` attribute, but since the struct consists of many other structs and since I don't want to access the struct members in Python itself, I'm thinking about an alternative how to create an identifier that can be reused.

I can change the definition of `connect()` as well as `foo()` as I'd like. I could also create another "identifier" struct if that would allow me to not have to recreate the struct in python.

**Update:**
It looks like I have to use the function `byref()` to achieve what I want. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref

The documentation states "The returned object can only be used as a foreign function call parameter" but I am not sure what to return in `connect()` then.

Comment: You need to set the `argtypes` and `restype` on your functions.

Comment: Thank you. Setting the argtypes to `[c_void_p]` worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an opaque structure (you do not know its members, or do not want to know its members), you should still create a class to represent that struct in python. You can then use this class to properly type your functions. This will help prevent bugs where you accidentally pass the wrong object as a "CustomStruct" pointer.

For example:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_int, c_void_p

mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib')

class CustomStructP(c_void_p):
    # subclassing c_void_p creates an opaque pointer type that is distinct
    # from c_void_p, and can only be instantiated as a pointer
    pass

create = mylib.create
create.argtypes = [c_int]
create.restype = CustomStructP

display = mylib.display
display.argtypes = [CustomStructP]
display.restype = None

delete = mylib.delete
delete.argtypes = [CustomStructP]
delete.restype = None

obj = create(10)
display(obj)
delete(obj)

display(CustomStructP())  # passing a null pointer
```

Now, if you tried something like: `display(c_void_p())`, you would get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\src\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    display(c_void_p())
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

The C code I used was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct customStruct {
    int val;
};

struct customStruct *
create(int val) {
    struct customStruct *obj = malloc(sizeof(struct customStruct));
    obj->val = val;
    return obj;
}

void
display(struct customStruct *obj) {
    if (obj) {
        printf("customStruct(%d) @ %p\n", obj->val, obj);
    }
    else {
        puts("customStruct is NULL");
    }
}

void
delete(struct customStruct *obj) {
    free(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a well structured and instructive answer.  I have used it to simulate OOP in my `C` library for `Python`.  I would have one question though.  There are many ways of wrapping `C`code for `Python` (https://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html).  Is there any advantage of using another method for the OOP problem of above?  Maybe some other method requires less initialization in Python?

Comment: I think it depends on your use case. `ctypes` is a great wrapping a library (ie you can't or don't want to access to the under lying source code), plus it is in the standard library. Writing a module in CPython gives you a huge amount of control, but it's much easier for things to go wrong (ie. create memory leaks). Cython is great for mixing pseudo-C/C++ code and python in the same source file, plus it does memory management for you. My experience with SWIG is limited, but it did allow for wrapping a library with the fewest lines of code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053325

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in comments already you need to set restype for the connect function and argtypes for the foo function on Python side.

In code it would look like this:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("some.dll")
lib.connect.restype = c_void_p
lib.foo.argtypes = c_void_p,

obj = lib.connect()
lib.foo(obj)
```

**Test**

A short test should verify that this gives the same pointer in your connection and foo function on the C side.

A slightly modified version of your code might look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct  {
    int x;
} customStruct;

static customStruct *connection_helper() {
    return malloc(sizeof(customStruct));
}

customStruct *connect()
{
    customStruct *obj = connection_helper();
    printf("connect: %p\n", obj);
    return obj;
}

void foo(customStruct * obj)
{
    printf("foo: %p\n", obj);
    //do something
}
```

If you run this you get something like:

```
connect: 0x7fa219e094a0
foo: 0x7fa219e094a0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. I'm just wondering why it is working with `c_void_p` as `restype` and `argtypes`. Why don't I have to create a custom pointer to `customStruct`?

Comment: You have to make sure that Python knows that the call of connect delivers a pointer and returns it correctly unchanged when you call foo with this pointer as an argument. Of course the situation would be different if you wanted to access fields of the structure on the Python side.

Comment: @brnk All pointers have the same width (on a given machine). The type of the pointer does not change this. The type of the pointer just helps stop you passing a string pointer as if it a `customStruct` pointer. Ideally you should define the `customStruct` in python so you that `ctypes` can detect if you're passing the wrong type into the C library.