# Wrapping C for object oriented programming in Python

Tags: python, c, oop

I have written a `C` code for chip communication with Raspberry Pi that includes **several** public functions.

To wrap it for use in `Python` I compiled the code into `so` file and used `ctypes`, because it was for me far the easiest way to do that.

However, there are two flaws to this method:

1. Python code is sometimes rather **quirky**.  For example, if the function takes an array for the argument, coding in Python looks like this:

> ```
> MCP4728 = cdll.LoadLibrary("./MCP4728.so")
>
> multipleexternal = MCP4728.multipleexternal
> multipleexternal.restype = c_int
> multipleexternal.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), c_bool]
>
> voltages=[0.5,1.5,2.5,2.5]
> floats = (c_float*4)(*voltages)
> multipleinternal(floats,False)
> ```

2. I do not know how to convert this for **object oriented programming**, so one can connect *two different chips at the same time*.
3. Finally, I want to make my software **public** and post it on `github`.  Maybe some other wrapping method is preferred in this case.

I am aware that there are many other methods of wrapping the `C` code for `Python`, as described [here](https://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html).  Could you give me a suggestion which method to use and perhaps even a object oriented programming example that would be most appropriate?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

This is not only a question of **syntax** but also of **concepts**.  The functions in the `C` library could be used for all chips, but a different set of variables held within a library is necessary for each chip.

So what should I do?  Define classes in Python, where creating a new object means creating new `struct` in the library connected to that object?  Or perhaps use new instance of `C` library for each object?  Or perhaps create classes/objects within `C` library?  I am completely clueless.

Comment: Let's focus on your *two different chips at the same time* problem.  What specifically prevents you from doing that?  Note that C supports struct objects, so unless you need something like inheritance (which is unlikely) ...

Comment: @robertharvey Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I thought that C has no OOP support. Perhaps I should look it up, as I never did OOP on C.

Comment: There's ways to support full-blown OOP in C, but my guess is you won't need that.

Comment: OOP in C is frighteningly simple, but you must maintain discipline when coding.  Basically, you give each function call a reference to its storage object of data type. This is a coding pattern you also know from Python when you declare functions that use "self". OOP is a coding pattern, not a feature.

Comment: The point being, you think you need OOP, but you probably don't.  What you probably do need is to maintain separate state for each chip.

Comment: I could probably create classes in Python and link functions of each object to functions written in C. However functions in C need a bunch of variables defined for each chip separately. I could put those variables in a struct, but I don't know how to define and link different instances of struct to my objects in Python.

Comment: You could provide a Python class which wraps all calls to the class and holds+provides the information specific to the instance when it calls your code

Comment: For a start, read a tutorial for writing Python extensions in C. This will give you an overview of what Python can do and how objects are represented there. Even if you stay with ctypes, it will be valuable inspiration, I hope. BTW: You mention you want to publish your code. Go ahead, do it now! Even if you later decide that the approach isn't future-proof, you can create a version 2 which may not be compatible but do things better.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Could you please give me a good link to such a tutorial?  I intend to publish the library as soon as I figure out the OOP part.  In current state, a user have to copy SO file  and PY library wrapper in the same folder as PY program and start working, so it is already doable.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the library is finally published here: https://github.com/marko-pi/MCP4728.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're talking about the Microchip MCP4728. This is an I2C attached device, and so it has an address on the I2C bus. If you're using it in its default factory condition, address 0b1100000. So, to have "two different chips", you'd need either 2 separate I2C buses, or take advantage of the reprogrammable addressing on the MCP4728 and set one of them to 0b1100001 (for which you'll need control of the /LDAC pin on the devices) so that 2 can exist on one I2C bus.

Either way, you'll need some sort of "context" for the device that you can pass to your C functions. That might simply be the bus number or the device address.

Or you could get creative and (as hinted at in the comments) have some sort of struct that, amongst other things, contains the device address or bus number. For that you'd need an initialiser, a function that'll act in an equivalent manner to a constructor. You'd pass this struct into each of the C functions, much as described by OI Sen. There's various settings available on the MCP4728 (like VRef selection, gain, and power state), so storing the current values of those in the struct would also be a good idea.

==EDIT==

Pygmalion (OP) has found a link to a useful answer, here [Python ctypes pointer to struct as identifier without member access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277376/python-ctypes-pointer-to-struct-as-identifier-without-member-access/62279723#62279723).

Also, it might be convenient to wrap the whole thing up in a python class, whereupon you could have a `__del__` destructor to ensure that the cleanup happens automatically.

Comment: Of course it is MCP4728.  My C library has both procedures for changing the address using bitbanging and standard I2C communication with the chip.  I have already written and published the Python code for that on my web page (according to my knowledge the only such code published in Python now).  But bitbanging in Python gives very inconsistent timing so I wanted to make everything more "professional" before putting it on github.  I have rewritten everything, bitbanging and standard I2C communication in C, and also made possible that both is done on I2C dedicated lines.

Comment: Everything is tested from Python and working, I "just" have to wrap it up for public use.  But this "just" might be the hardest part to be done.

Comment: I solved my problem by creating `struct` that holds data of each individual chip.  On initialisation, I am creating new instances of the `struct` with `malloc` and passing the pointer to them back to Python.  Python then passes that pointer to individual functions. There is a description how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62279723/2957687.  If this is what you had in your mind, please add the link to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Pygmalion that's a good answer, added here as requested.