# Python ctypes access violation due to invalid pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a dll and its header file that define quite a number of functions to access data in a special format. Following other solutions, I am able to get a basic start with ctypes that seems to work but as soon as I attempt to use a returned file pointer I receive the access violation so I suspect I am using the pointers incorrectly.

I'm following example code in C which lays out creating a new context, then opening the file, so I believe that part is ok. I just can't seem to do anything with the returned file reference. I do get `file` returned as an int after calling `sie_file_open` whereas the documentation says that the errors from the library return null. I've got a bunch of different functions to use with the file pointer, but even the most basic `sie_release` fails.

Taking the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62279723) to use classes to manage the pointers (there will be many more needed to access the data later), I have:

```
from ctypes import *

libsie = cdll.LoadLibrary('libsie.dll')

#Set the SIE context
class pt_sie_context(c_void_p):
    pass

libsie.sie_context_new.argtypes = None
libsie.sie_context_new.restype = pt_sie_context

context = libsie.sie_context_new()

#Open the SIE file
class pt_sie_file(c_void_p):
    pass

libsie.sie_file_open.argtypes = [pt_sie_context,c_char_p]
libsie.sie_file_open.restypes = pt_sie_file

fpath = 'H2.sie'
file = libsie.sie_file_open(context,fpath.encode('utf-8'))

libsie.sie_release.argtypes = [pt_sie_file]
libsie.sie_release.restypes = None

libsie.sie_release(file) #access violation here
```

And from the header file:

```
typedef void sie_Context;
typedef void sie_File;

SIE_DECLARE(sie_Context *) sie_context_new(void);
SIE_DECLARE(sie_File *) sie_file_open(void *context_object, const char *name);
SIE_DECLARE(void) sie_release(void *object);
```

I'm relatively new to this whole process as well as C in general so any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in your solution.  Does the library work correctly called from C?  Is `sie_release` supposed to release a file object or a context object?  It's not clear from the header.

Comment: Yes, I can compile the example program and it works correctly. Looking into this a little further, the access violation is always 8 (bits?) higher than the value of file, e.g. console output is 'access violation reading 0x00000000792562F8' and hex(file) is '0x792562f0'. Could that mean anything?

Comment: It thinks the pointer is invalid.  If you hadn't set `.argtypes` to a `c_void_p` derivative I'd say a 64-bit pointer got truncated, but it looks like you've done that correctly.

Comment: You never check what the functions return. If they fail (and return *NULL*) the behavior you're seeing is correct. Use proper error handling (*sie\_check\_exception*).

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Unfortunately, `sie_check_exception` does return null up until the access violation and the returned `file` appears to be a pointer. It's starting to look like the dll frees the pointer after it returns, but I don't know why that doesn't also happen when obtaining the context.